# How to calculate "general" integral $\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)^2dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functions

How to calculate "general" integral:

$\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)^2dx$?

Comment: There is no "general" method for this. It depends on the function.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's a bit beyond just being a "general" integral as $f\left(x\right)$ matters. For example, if we have
$$\int\left(\log\left|x\right|\right)^2dx$$
the methods we would use to integrate are somewhat different than if you were trying to solve $$\int\sin^2\left(x\right)dx$$
or $$\int\left(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\right)^2dx,$$
given that $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ etc.

However, if you can show that
\begin{align}
\int_a^bf\left(x\right)^2\:dx=1,
\end{align}
on some interval $\left[a,b\right]$, then $f\left(x\right)$ is said to be *normed*.